# Sell only a stock profits

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis

Assuming one have 100 stocks of a company.
Assuming this stock goes 1% up and down zig zagging for a year.

1. Person A keep his money in the stock for a year and then test results ( profit is 0 )
2. Person B keep his money in the stock but every time it’s up 1% he takes ONLY the 1% profits and leave the rest invested. Test results after a year.

Is approach 2 have a name, and is it better or worse than 1 regarding risk and profits ? ( including trading fees).

Is one approach better than the other if the zig zag is wilder and not equal ( in a real world stock) so the stock price is different after a year ?

Comment: If you own 100 shares, and you sell 1 share every time it goes up 1%, what do you do with money from the share you sell?

Comment: You're not really going to know whether A or B comes out ahead until you know the final price that A sells at.

Comment: The OP's premise is that there is no profit at the end of the time period because share price is unchanged at the end of the time period.

Comment: If you ignore the mechanical challenges of selling a specific percentage (that may not "line up" with the number of shares you have), as-is this isn't strictly answerable. The answer depends on what you mean by "goes 1% up and down" (specifically, was the *down* actually 1% of the now-101% value, or 1% of the original value) and how many zig zags there are. Essentially, option two is just slowly converting the stock into cash throughout the year. The difference in value at the end of the year between the two options will be at most the fluctuation (1%) and at least zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 2 is not really possible.**

Let's say you buy your initial 100 shares (let's say at $100 per share) and then the price goes up 1%.

The only way to "take" that 1% profit is to sell 1 off your hundred shares. You now have $101 in cash and 99 shares left.

Then the price zig-zags down and back up and you want to "take" that 1% profit again, except now you have 99 shares so you can't take only 1%, you have to take 1.01 %.  So now you have $202 in cash and 98 shares.

This repeats with the percentage you have to sell increasing each time. Before long you are not selling 1% or 1.01% but 10%, 25%, etc.

At the end of the year, you would have sold all your stock and made 1% profit. Most of (if not all of or even *more* than all of) the profit would have been eaten up in fees.

Answer (score 1):

2 is called day trading or scalping depending on timeframe.

It is better IF YOU CAN PULL IT OFF - which most people are woefully incompetent at. Actually on any trading. It also is not "being invested", it is "trading" - which means you will spend a lot of time doing it, which means you better earn more than you could otherwise earn. It is more a job than passive investment.

Comment: Hey thanks but I don’t think that’s what I was looking for. I know what day trading is, I am asking regarding the signal/math/curve aspects, I am looking for a deep calculation of such approach because I think it’s not obvious if they are equal in numbers. And I do my trading using software I write, so..

Comment: In other words in a pure saw signal is person B have more or less money? And with any other wilder signal ? I don’t talk about trying to hit the curve only on the tops, but an ideal situation when one sold only the ups.

Comment: @hkrlys not being funny, but if you are writing your own software to manage trading then what is stopping you doing a quick spreadsheet model to answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

> Person B keep his money in the stock but every time it’s up 1% he takes ONLY the 1% profits and leave the rest invested.

You cannot take "ONLY the 1% profits and leave the rest invested" because each share has a 1% profit.  In order to realize that 1% gain you must sell all 100 shares.

> Is approach 2 have a name, and is it better or worse than 1 regarding risk and profits ? ( including trading fees).

It is called either day trading or swing trading, depending on the time frame.  If one books more profits than losses then it will outperform Person A' s buy and hold, excluding commissions which at this point, you shouldn't be paying since most major brokers have eliminated them.  SEC sell fees are almost negligible.  If the stock collapses and Person B is out of the market, he outperforms by not losing.

The buy and hold approach of Person A will outperform if price moves up more than 1% and Person B is out of the market, waiting for the reversion back to the starting price.

Comment: The first paragraph is not correct: If you have 100 shares worth $50 each, and the price of the shares rises 1% to $50.50, [moving your total investment from $5,000 to $5,050], you can realize the $50.00 of profit by selling 1 share. This leaves you with $5,000 in share value [99 x $50.5], and $50 in cash, give or take $0.50 rounding error on each side because you can only sell a whole share.

Comment: Note that the question asker has a crude understanding of 'taking profit', and does not seem fully aware of the fact that the unrealized gain exists whether or not it is cashed out, so for their purposes, cashing out the profit seems to be what is meant by 'taking it'.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon not sure i agree with you about my understanding (as a signal processing engineer that trade for a while now). It may be my English, but you are also wrong, because when you cash out, you are less exposed to next changes, and when you don't take profits, you have more shares and so exposed more to a future crash. So person B after 10 months will have profits, and very little shares, and if a crash of 30% arrives at month 9, he is ok. Guess you didn't put this into your equation.

Comment: @hkrlys Okay, but your question is pretty naive in how it assumes a known end price - if you want to completely avoid risk just take all your investments out of the market. If a permanent price drop occurs on day 1 and is never recovered from, both methods are the same impact because you never had any initial profits to 'take' from. Your question effectively asks if something is more than less of something, so the language used doesn't convey knowledge on the subject.

Comment: @Grade 'Eh' Bacon - I disagree.  Buy 100 shares @$50 for $5,000.  Price rises 1% to $50.50 and 100 shares now worth $5,050. Sell 1 share for $50.50,  lowering cost basis and money at risk ($50 of principal and $50 cents of profit). Per the OP's premise, share price drops back to $50 (all profit has now been  lost on  99 shares). Buy 1 share @$50, restoring the original position.  You now own 100 shares @$50 with a cost basis of $5,000 along with only **50 cents of cash profit** which is far from having booked the 1% of profit ($50 when share price was $50.50). It's 1/100th of 1%.

Comment: @BobBaerker Remember - per the OP's understanding, when you cash out, that is 'taking profit', and the risk to the remaining shares is a separate question (he has clarified here that this seems to be his approach). From his perspective, the 'profit' is retained, and the amount at risk is kept consistent.

Comment: @BobBaerker: There was a $50 gain, and a $50.50 cash out, which is roughly equal to the profit.  Now, to the taxman, you'll only pay tax on the $0.50 capital gain on the 1 share, and the other $50 cashed out came from the basis.  But the tax treatment does not make it wrong for the OP to say "there was $50 profit, I took it out, and I still have a $5000 investment".  A $5000 investment with a $4950 basis is still a $5000 investment.  A $50.50 withdrawal with only $0.50 of taxable gain is still a $50.50 withdrawal.  In this scenario the trader has withdrawn his entire gain, only 1% is taxable.

Comment: Grade 'Eh' Bacon - In reading the question again, I'm now wondering what the OP's premise is.  If it is what my last comment addressed (share price zig zagging up 1% then retracing), I still feel the same way (sell one share when it rises and then repurchase one share when it drops back down to original purchase).  Now I'm wondering if he meant selling an amount of shares equivalent to share price rising 1% then selling again when it rises another  1%?  If so then my answer is not applicable.  I'll take a pass until there's clarification from him.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  - I accept what you suggest as a possibility  but the OP's question specifically refers to the zig zagging from up 1% then back down to flat.  He may have taken out an amount of money to what he presumes to be the profit but the zig zagging takes most of it away.  And if the position is flat at the end of this (his premise), he has not truly realized his profit.  I'm going to bow out of this convo since the question is poorly phrased and there could be multiple interpretations of exactly what is transpiring with share price.